# Show DialogFragment from OnPositiveClickListener

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

My code has two dialog fragments, and I'm trying to call one from another's onDialogPositiveClick. I can't figure out how to do this? I've moved around my getSupportFragmentManager, but nothing works.

```
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) throws IOException {       
 switch (dialog.getTag()) {

"case1":{

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
   DialogFragment dialog = new AddItemFragment();
   dialog.show(fm, "dialog");}

break;

"case2":{
}
}
```

EDIT: I misspelled my cases.

Comment: That's not exactly how a `switch` statement works. `switch(dialog.getTag().toString(){ \n case "case1": \n //your code \n break; \n case "case2": \n //your code \n break;` While `\n` equals a line break. Also, since you want to compare `Strings`, I recommend using `if(dialog.getTag().toString().equals("case1"){ ... };`

Answer (score 1):

in case it have to be only integer values. So use `int id_tag = (Integer) v.getTag();`

and put only int values: `v.setTag(<myintval>);`

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in UiThread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new AddItemFragment();
        dialog.show(fm, "dialog");}
    }
});
```